# C++ Pre and Post Increment

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, post-increment, pre-increment

I'm having trouble with overloading the post increment method.
My pre increment is fine.
I also have pre/post decrements, and they both work perfectly.
The increment and decrement body should be similar. The only difference should be ++/--, but I'm not sure why my post increment won't work like my post decrement.

pre increment

```
upDate upDate::operator++() {
   int julian = convertDateToJulian(datePtr[0], datePtr[1], datePtr[2]);
   julian++;
   convertDateToGregorian(julian);
   return (*this);
}
```

post increment

```
upDate upDate::operator++(int num) {
   upDate temp (*this);
   int julian = convertDateToJulian(datePtr[0], datePtr[1], datePtr[2]);
   julian++;
   convertDateToGregorian(julian);
   return temp;
}
```

post decrement

```
upDate upDate::operator--(int num) {
   upDate temp(*this);
   int julian = convertDateToJulian(datePtr[0], datePtr[1], datePtr[2]);
   julian--;
   convertDateToGregorian(julian);
   return temp;
}
```

This is my main:

```
upDate d5(11, 10, 2004);
++d5;
cout << d5 << endl;
cout << "Expected November 11, 2004\n" << endl;

//not working
upDate d6(11, 11, 2004);
d5++;
cout << d6 << endl;
cout << "Expected November 12, 2004\n" << endl;

upDate d11(12, 3, 1992);
d11--;
cout << d11 << endl;
cout << "Expected: December 2, 1992\n" << endl;
```

The output is:
//the date was originally Nov 10 2004
//++incr
November 11, 2004
Expected: November 11, 2004

//the date was originally Nov 11 2004
//incr++
November 11, 2004 //output should not be this
Expected: November 12, 2004

//the date was originally Dec 2 1992
//decr--
December 1, 1992
Expected: December 1, 1992

Comment: @presiuslitelsnoflek The two increment operators look ok, but the post-decrement one is not working correctly, not is the expectation correct.

Comment: Your "not working" is incrementing `d5` from the prior test again, not `d6`.

Comment: @FredLarson: But not after the increment, when he shows `d6`.

Comment: @FredLarson what? `d6` is created as `11/11/2004` and never updated before it is printed...

Comment: @FredLarson no. `d6` is initially 11/11/2004, is unchanged, and that is the output given. Its a typo.

Comment: Ah, I see. `d5` is incremented and `d6` is printed.

Comment: Also note that you are not testing the return value of the pre/post increment. `cout << d5++ << endl;` and `cout << ++d5 << endl`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo in your main:

```
//not working
upDate d6(11, 11, 2004);
d6++;  // <---- you have d5++;
cout << d6 << endl;
cout << "Expected November 12, 2004\n" << endl;
```

Comment: Omg....Thank you! I was going insane! Just one logical error can make a whole difference..

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo. In this code snippet

```
//not working
upDate d6(11, 11, 2004);
d5++;
cout << d6 << endl;
cout << "Expected November 12, 2004\n" << endl;
```

you applied the post increment operator to **d5**

```
d5++;
```

but outputed **d6**

```
cout << d6 << endl;
```

d6 was not changed.

Also take into account that the correct declaration of the pre-increment operator  is

```
upDate & upDate::operator++();
```

that is the operator should return **lvalue.** while your operator returns a temporary object.